# Event to be triggered when a button is clicked also triggers another event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to trigger an even when a button `<input type="button" id="btn-halt"/>` is clicked.

```
$("#btn-halt").click(function(){
   alert("Halt button was clicked")
})
```

However I have another event that is triggered on any other element click.

```
$("em, div, input:not(#btn-halt), textarea, ul, ol, form, li, select, table, label, tr, td, span, a, p, img, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5").click(function (event) {
 // do stuff
})
```

How do I prevent the second event from being triggered as well. I think it is being triggered because the `<input type="button" id="btn-halt"/>` is located within a `div` and when any `div` is clicked it triggers the second event.

Comment: #btn-halt is input button and you are calling a function inside this so it should not trigger for another elements. could you show us a jsfiddle for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect that you are encountering is called as `event bubbling`, you can prevent it by using the following snippet.

Try,

```
$("#btn-halt").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: Thanks, yep that should do it